# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-validatecommad"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I saw this code on the Internet. The original author used Python 3.3.
I searched the whole network and couldn't find a similar answer. I don't know what's wrong

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
v1 = StringVar()
v2 = StringVar()
v3 = StringVar()

def test(content):
    return content.isdigit()

testCMD = master.register(test)
e1 = Entry(master,textvariable=v1,validate="key",\
           validatecommad=(testCMD, '%p')).grid(row=0, column=0)
Label(master,text="+").grid(row=0, column=1)

e2 = Entry(master,textvariable=v2,validate="key",\
           validatecommand=(testCMD, '%p')).grid(row=0, column=2)
Label(master,text="+").grid(row=0, column=3)

e3 = Entry(master,textvariable=v3,state="readonly").grid(row=0, column=4)

def calc():
    result = int(v1.get())+int(v2.get())
    v3.set(str(result))

Button(master,text="计算结果",command=calc).grid(row=1,column=2)
mainloop()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a typo in the first entry definition, `validatecommad` should be `validatecommand` (like in the second call to Entry)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This problem is indeed a cerebral palsy problem, but it is a common problem for me, a non-native English novice